# How do I get the type indicator in PyScripter to show up at the end of the line I clicked on?

Tags: python, pyscripter

When I click somewhere in the PyScripter IDE I would expect the little type indicator to appear at the end of the line that I clicked on, like this:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwnF5.jpg)

But instead when I click somewhere in the the type indicator will appear exactly where I click, like this:

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFvdS.jpg)

This is extremely annoying, how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code?

Comment: PyScripter is open source but I am not sure how to get access to the source code.

Comment: @AlfieHughes https://github.com/pyscripter/pyscripter source code is on github

Comment: Reason to ask is because you can only "fix" this (quoted, because what you are seeing is actually just a preference of its writers) is to change it in the source. Apparently, its source is in Pascal. That means you can't use the Python tag for this question – it's merely the language in which you program, not the program itself.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools, Options, Editor Options and in the Editor tab, uncheck "Scroll past EOL".